# Opens splash screen and App gets crashed - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

App works most of the time. I encounter an issue sporadically that when I tap on the App icon it will open the App, splash screen, and closes. I'm not able to see the login screen of the App. Please advise what could be the reason for this. Also, is there a way I can debug this on the device? Please advise.

This is happening in different situations but This time it started happening when I change the device time by mistake to `November 2022`.

Please see the App Analytics on the Device:(not sure this related to app or generic one)

```
{"timestamp":"2019-01-15 16:39:35.93 -0800","bug_type":"211","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.1.2 (16C101)","incident_id":"368FAE78-6862-41B4-BB6B-D7D94155A807"}
{"_marker":"<metadata>","_preferredUserInterfaceLanguage":"en","_userInterfaceLanguage":"en","_userSetRegionFormat":"US","startTimestamp":"2022-01-11T12:36:53Z","version":"1.0"}
{"_marker":"<end-of-file>"}
```

Note: On the simulator following message is displaying in the log:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed

Answer (score 0):

If your app crashed on startup it probably ran into an exception. Unfortunately there isn't much you can do to debug an iOS app without a Mac at this time. It's something we hope to introduce but that isn't trivial.

If you have a pro account turn on crash protection as it might send you a log indicating the reason of the crash. You can also add more logging which might help. There are some tools to view the device console, in a Mac you can do that with xcode but I understand some tools exist for Windows as well. With detailed logging you should be able to track the point where the crash occurred.

Otherwise you would need to use trial and error with the process of elimination. For that you will need a consistent way to reproduce the issue.

If the clock of the device isn't set correctly certificates will become invalid and will stop working as they have expiry dates. That also means the server HTTPS certificates will become invalid.

Comment: how can i debug in xcode if the crash happens sporadically? Please advise.

Comment: crash protection - error like crashing on splash screen, where do you think i have to add the logging. Please advise,

Comment: You will need a way to reproduce this crash so it occurs when you are in xcode. I suggest logging literally after every line until you get a general sense of the cause of the crash. You can also look at the crash files through xcode, they are often gibberish but can include the reason for failure e.g. memory access, out of memory, null etc.

Comment: Is there a way you can point out the guide to perform Xcode testing process. can we Xcode testing with .ipa file only if not how can we debug cn1 code in Xcode.

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html

Comment: Shai..it is very hard to reproduce the issue on xcode as the issue is sporadic. Even with crash protection, I don't receive any log related to crash happened. Please advise.